# Convert time duration (BigDecimal value + time units) to milliseconds long

Tags: java, converters, long-integer, bigdecimal, duration

I have to create a function that has 2 input parameters:
`Time duration` in BigDecimal (precision 38, scale 6)
and
`TimeUnitsType enum` (DAYS, HOURS, MINUTES or SECONDS).

And I need to get `long` value (milliseconds) as a result;
As I understand, the `longValue()` method from `BigDecimal` won't work precisely here as it set scale to 0, and `longValueExact()` will throw `ArithmeticException("Overflow")` (because precision - scale > 19)

```
public static long convertTimeToMillis(BigDecimal time, TimeUnitsType timeUnitsType) {
    long timeLong = time.longValue();
    switch (timeUnitsType) {
        case DAYS:
            return TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(timeLong);
        case HOURS:
            return TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(timeLong);
        case MINUTES:
            return TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(timeLong);
        default:
            return TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(timeLong);
    }
}
```

So I need to make individual calculation for each case separately. Can you please help me? BigDecimal operations scares me a little, because I haven't work with them before :) And the precision is required in the rest of the task.

P.S. Java version is 1.6

Comment: Please define exactly what `BigDecimal time` is representing. Is `time` duration in the unit of `timeUnitsType` or is `time` in it's own unit and being converted to the equivalent duration in `timeUnitsType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `time` is in the unit of `timeUnitsType` and you are converting that time (in its units) to milliseconds then there is always the chance of an overflow. *`long` simply cannot hold more than 19 digits*, while here you could have 32 digits 6 decimal places in seconds and converting that to milliseconds would make it up to 35 digits. 32 digit days to milliseconds is even worse...

Are you sure you need to convert this `BigDecimal` in its `TimeUnit` to a single `long` in milliseconds?

`BigDecimal.longValueExact()` will throw an exception if there would be any information lost. So if you check for that exception and handle it then I guess things will be ok.

Comment: Yes, I need to convert to millis here (this is a requirement), because there are a lot of further calculations and there should be a single format. So as I understood - I can use the longValueExact() result just wrapping its exception to my custom one, right?

Comment: Yes, `BigDecimal.longValueExact()` will throw an exception if there would be any information lost. So if you check for that exception and handle it then I guess things will be ok.

Comment: Thanks, I will check if this works accurately. This is certainly the simplest solution if so.

Comment: @alexkov If this answered your questions then an 'accept' would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a reason that you are allowing up to 6 decimal positions in the incoming value, so you can't just ignore them. Do the conversions yourself, creating a new BigDecimal that retains the decimal positions. Once you have milliseconds, round that BigDecimal. Finally, compare the BigDecimal to Long.MAX_VALUE and MIN_VALUE. If it is outside those bounds, throw an exception.